# RealmSwift with xCode 8

Tags: realm, swift3, xcode8

I developed an app using swift 2.2 and Xcode 7.3.1 and I've used Realm 1.0.1 for the database adding manually the framework to the project.
Today I've updated to xCode 8 but now Realm doesn't work anymore.

I've tried to both "Convert to Swift 2.3" and "Convert to Swift 3" but I always get this error:
[image]

Is it possible to continue to use Realm with Xcode 8?
Or I have to change the database with another one?

What do you suggest me?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there will be official support for Swift 3, currently you have to build Realm yourself using the instructions [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3796).

Comment: Although people seem to be coming up with better workarounds at the end of the thread :  https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3796#issuecomment-247366784

Comment: oh, and apparently RealmSwift 1.1.0 which is coming soon, will run on Swift 3.0. This week or next week, apparently.

Comment: Ohh wow, I hope so. With the manually building is a little bit complicated.